# Xamarin Forms: Resource strings

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been developing mobile apps with Xamarin for six months and Xamarin Forms is the only way that I did it. Two days ago I came across to an article that suggested me to use recourse strings via xml instead of hardcoding them. I researched it for android and general idea leaded me to use recourse strings.

My question is:

I created an abstract class called BaseLang in portable library which looks similar like this:

```
public abstract class BaseLang
{
     public abstract string Text { get; }
}
```

And for every language i create,

```
public class EngLang : BaseLang
{
    public override string Text { get { return "Welcome"; } }
}
```

And I declare my EngLang class as a static variable at the first time the app is built and use my strings with it. My actual question is, is this ok or I should use resource strings and use dependency injection to call them?

Comment: Android and iOS have different 'native' ways of handling string localization.  But with Xamarin Forms, you can use RESX files (which is a totally different mechanism).  See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/localization/ for more details.  I have personally used RESX strings with iOS, Android, and Windows RT (this took some extra work).  I believe it will work with all other Xamarin Forms platforms as well.

Comment: What is the advantage of using it instead of classes?

Comment: I believe that RESX is generally faster and easier (for the developers) than using a set of custom classes.  For starters, the system will mostly handle selecting an appropriate file (with a language) based on the user's device.  Secondly, writing custom classes and your own locator pattern (picking the class that fits the current user) is a lot of overhead (code writing).  RESX essentially compiles into these classes you are writing.  Visual Studio makes editing the RESX very easy.  Microsoft also has technologies that build off of RESX to make adding language translations easier - MAT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to take a look to resx files. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoLocalized